# Why is agent.getNetworkNode returning null the second time a resource is seized?

Tags: anylogic

agent.getNetworkNode returns the INode location of a resource when I seize it for the first time. But after it leaves its location and moves through a simple flowchart with the seizing agent (moveTo, delay, release) the resource returns to its home node and seizing it again returns null.

Am I supposed to refresh the location somehow after releasing? Thanks.